# Java Dependencies of jar files

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

To resolve issue of dependencies, maven is one of the solution. But maven does not include latest version.

Question:
**1) Is there any solution for solving dependency issue other than maven?

2) How can i get latest version in maven?**

Thanks to all

Comment: "But maven does not include latest version." latest version of... what?

Comment: You could use Gradle, which is Maven's hip little brother.  Not sure what you mean by "maven does not include latest version."

Comment: for example to work on jasper Report,latest version is 6.6.0 released, but maven include max 3.5.3 version

Comment: @Manku Maven has [version 6.6.0 since May 29, 2018.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.6.0) which is exactly the day of the release of the version.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jasperreports/jasperreports shows only 3.5.3

Comment: can you tell me link showing latest version

Comment: The links is already there?

Comment: Also on your link it directly says: **"Note: This artifact was moved to:"** with a **direct link** to the correct artifact. Come on now please.

Comment: Then what about openCv latest version available in maven

Comment: Maven does not include a version of a dependency. Only the pom defined versions or transitive dependencies are given by dependencies...Furthermore by using the search engine of Central like this: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjasperreports  you will see which versions exist for the particular artifact....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to include a latest version of a dependency, If that is the case you can use,
Maven tag

```
<version>LATEST</version>
```

or

```
  <version>[1.0.0,)</version> 
  this will get the highest dependency version available grater than 1.0.0.
```

And note `<version>LATEST</version>`  does not work for maven versions 3.x.

Comment: I can not recommend to use `LATEST` cause with Maven 3.5.2 ...this will produce warnings..apart from being deprecated for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about transitive dependencies maven uses dependency which is placed nearest to root.

For example:
A depends on B, B depends on C(v 1.1)
A directly depends on C(1.0).

In that situation, C(1.0) will be included in the application classpath.

More info [here](https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Hope, it will help.